# Tektro HD-M290, change to a dropbar lever configuration. Which levers are compatible?

Tags: hydraulic-disc-brake, conversion, brake-levers, drop-bar, tektro

I want to change my cowboy flat handlebar to a drop bar. I have Tektro HD-M290 brakes and I'm searching for a compatible model of drop bar levers.

The bicycle has automatic speeds, so I just need brake levers.

I can't find any info on what is compatible with the hydraulic brakes and I would like not to change all the brake system.

Any Tektro drop levers compatible, or another brand maybe?

Answer (score 2):

The issue of cross-brand hydraulic lever-caliper compatibility has been discussed here previously. See this question and its answers: [Hydraulic disc brake - lever compatibility](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/67743/hydraulic-disc-brake-lever-compatibility). TLDR: no evidence for compatibility between brands.

Drop bar brake-only levers almost do not exist. All Shimano and SRAM drop bar levers integrate shifting and braking functions. The only product I know of is the TRP Hylex levers. These are designed for single-speed cyclocross bikes, which of course do not need gear shifting.

It's possible Tektro makes a similar product that is compatible with their brake calipers, but I could not find anything on their site.

What I would do is replace both the levers and calipers with TRP Hylex, and have the confidence that they are compatible and will not degrade or fail.

Comment: Tektro and TRP (Tektro Racing Program) is one single company with TRP being just a premium brand. There is a decent likelyhood it might work (but who knows, that's why I did not post an answer).

Comment: @VladimirF that's good info. What the OP could do is contact Tektro/TRP and ask about compatibility.

Comment: Tektro and TRP use the same fittings. https://trpcycling.com/product/olive-and-barb-set/
Shimano and SRAM both make a  considerable number of drop bar brake-only levers: BL-U5010, BL-RX600, BL-RX810. SRAM: Rival 1, Force 1, Apex 1, S-900 (aero and std.), S-500 (aero and std)

Comment: @thelawnet I was not aware of the Shimano and SRM brake-only levers, Thanks for the info.

Comment: @thelawnet, thank you for the info, it is another path I'll certainly take a look at.

Comment: You wouldn't be able to use SRAM with Tektro because they use different brake fluid. Shimano and TRP is more likely to work but you'd have to try....